# How to connect buttons to texts that changes on vertical slide?

Tags: javascript, css, onclick, dom-events

I don't know if it is a laborious question for whoever's going to answer this, and I'm sorry in this case, but I'm lost and here's the deal:

I have a vertical navigation bar at the left side of the page, and some text on the right side. Each button of the navigation has its own text, and I want it to be like: every time one of the buttons is clicked, the actual text slides (up or down), giving space to other text.

I need it to be in the same page, without link changing (in other words, without "a" tag). Do I need JavaScript to do this, or it can be done only by CSS?

In JavaScript case, I think it should be done with the `onClick` event, but I don't know how to proceed in this case. Can someone help me on this?
I hope I've made my problem clear, because I'm not fluent in English.

Here's a very simple demonstration, I hope it to be useful:
https://jsfiddle.net/4cgsn76t/3/

```
<ul>

<li>Button 1</li>
<li>Button 2</li>
<li>Button 1</li>
<li>Button 2</li>
</ul>
<!-- Text below connected to Button 1 -->
<p>
"At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga."
</p>
<!-- Text below connected to Button 2 -->
<p>
"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
</p>

ul {

  float:left;
}

ul li {
  list-style:none;
  width:100px;
  height: 30px;
  background:blue;
  margin-top:15px;
  margin-right:30px;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

p {
  width:300px;
  float:left;
  font-size:12px;
}

p:nth-child(2) {
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the lists of `li`s and `p`s using Document#querySelectorAll. Iterate the list items with `.forEach()`, and add an event listener to each item. When one is clicked hide all paragraphs, and show the relevant text:

```js
var para = document.querySelectorAll('p');

document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(function(el, i) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    para.forEach(function(p) {
      p.style.display = 'none';
    });

    para[i].style.display = 'block'
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  float: left;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: blue;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

p {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
}

p:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Button 1</li>
  <li>Button 2</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <!-- Text below connected to Button 1 -->
  <p>
    "At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia
    animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga."
  </p>
  <!-- Text below connected to Button 2 -->
  <p>
    "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo."
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks!

When the button is clicked, I want it to change of color. Is there a way to make the first button already with a "clicked appearance" when the page is opened?

Comment: Create a class `active` (or any fitting name) with the style you want. Add it manually to the 1st list item, when clicked remove it from all items, and add it to the clicked item.

Comment: Do this active style also needs to be made on JavaScript, or can I make it either on JavaScript or CSS?

Comment: Create a [CSS class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors), and move it around using JS.

Comment: Just one more question: is it okay to write into the parenthesis like"document.querySelectorAll('#element-id')"?